# Can I integrate files within a smart contract?

Tags: smart-contract-wallets, data

I want to create a smart contract, let you use files like docx, doc, pdf etc. with the reason of keep those files in the smart contract system and use them when the users of the smart contract requires it

***is it possible to use files as input and use a files visualization system as output of the smart contract?***

**Is it possible to use a file in smart contract's system like a feature of the smart contract's function?**

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to use files as input and use a files visualization system as output of the smart contract?

In practice it is not, because various limitations in smart contract execution environment.

Comment: And is it possible to use some type of data from external sources and to use it in smart contract?

Comment: [It is not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63004386/315168).